# Add private IPs to a file - Terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to be able to dump the private IPs for the EC2 servers created by Terraform.

```
resource "aws_instance" "hello"  {
  count = "3"
  tags {
      Name = "${var.name}"

  }

  ami = "${var.AWS_AMI}"
  instance_type = "${var.aws_instance_type}"
  subnet_id = "${var.aws_subnet_id}"
```

How will I dump the private IPs created for this instance as a comma separated list to a file so that another bash script can read it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to specify an output variable in the terraform file :

Example:

```
output hello_ec2_private_ip {
  value = "${join(",",aws_instance.hello.*.private_ip)}"
}
```

then use the [terraform output](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html) command to list the output
and pipe it to a file

Example:

```
terraform output  hello_ec2_private_ip > private_hello.txt
```